# How to create a boolean mask in tensorflow with middle range only set to True using indexing specified in another tensor

Tags: tensorflow, indexing, mask, tensor, creation

I have a tensor of shape [None, 1] consisting of a value for each batch. Using this tensor, I have to create a boolean mask with values set to true starting from the index value (from the tensor) of the corresponding batch to a fixed length and rest all set to false.

Example, consider the index tensor to be

```
[[1],[2],[2]]
```

Suppose the desired length of timesteps for each batch is 5 and the fixed length is 2, then for the first batch, in the indexes starting from 1 and ending at 2 (as fixed length=2), the values are to be set True. Likewise for other batches. i.e, I want my boolean mask created to be

```
[[False,True,True,False,False],
 [False,False,True,True,False],
 [False,False,True,True,False]]
```

How to achieve the above without having to do individually for each batch? And preferably without using ragged feature in tensorflow?

```
index < tf.range(number_of_timesteps)
```

The above can be used for setting True in the extremes, but I could not find a way to set True in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Solving your example can be done with a combination of tf.one_hot and tf.roll.

```
input = [[1],[2],[2]]
intermediate_output = tf.one_hot(input, 5)
output = intermediate_output + tf.roll(intermediate_output, shift=1,axis=2)
```

If you need to convert to boolean from zeros and ones

```
output = tf.where(tf.equal(output, 1), True, False)
```

Explanation:
tf.one_hot is used to convert your indices to an intermediate one hot representation. Next tf.roll shifts the intermediate representation by 1. Combining this with the intermediate representation and converting to boolean returns your desired output.

EDIT:

I don't see a good way other than a for loop to extend this to multiple timesteps. The below code will generate your desired output

```
input = [[1],[2],[2]]
intermediate_output = tf.one_hot(input, 5)

outputs = []
timesteps = 3
for i in range(timesteps):
  outputs.append(tf.roll(intermediate_output, shift=i,axis=2))

output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.unstack(outputs, timesteps), 2)
output = tf.where(tf.equal(output, 1), True, False)
```

Comment: Hi, I would also like to have fixed length as variable. incase the length is 3,then output should be                                                                                                     `[[False,True,True,True,False],
 [False,False,True,True,True],
 [False,False,True,True,True]]`